# How do I export data frames I have created in Google Colab with pandas, to a new Google Sheets file?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, gspread

I have read countless posts on here about using gspread to output data to Google Sheets, but everytime I try an example, it doesn't work for me.

Basically I am currently reading in data from an existing Google Sheets doc, working on it with Pandas, then I want to output the data to a brand new Google Sheets doc.

I have figured out how to create a new Google Sheets doc, a new worksheet and how to manually update individual cell ranges but what I need to do is export a data frame to the sheet.

I start my script off with the following code block. I understand there are different ways of working with the API but this way worked for me:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

After all the work I do with the data, I now just need to know how to take a df I create e.g. a simple 2 column df and put it into a new Google Sheets doc without getting errors.

I have read the documentation and countless posts but I just can't seem to get it to work. There are other things I need to figure out how to do with gspread but this is a blocker I have right now.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new worksheet in a new or an existing spreadsheet.

To create a new spreadsheet and add workbook, do

```py
sh = gc.create('A new spreadsheet')
```

To append a new workbook to an existing spreadsheet, do:

```py
sh = gc.open('An existing spreadsheet')
```

Assuming your `dataframe` is named `df`, the following will convert your column names and values to lists respectively.

```py
df_col_names = [df.columns.values.tolist()] 
df_col_values = df_pwv_sel_unp.values.tolist()
```

Then add a worksheet to your created or opened spreadsheet

```py
#get the dimensions of the dataframe
df_rows = df.shape[0]
df_cols = df.shape[1]
#create worksheet
worksheet = sh.add_worksheet(title="A worksheet", rows=df_rows, cols=df_cols).
```

Now use the `update()` method to write data to the newly created worksheet

```py
worksheet.update(df_col_names + df_col_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [gspread_pandas](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) as well:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread_pandas
from google.auth import default
import pandas as pd
creds, _ = default()

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=['T'])
spread = gspread_pandas.Spread('New Spreadsheet Name', creds=creds, create_spread=True)
spread.df_to_sheet(df, index=False, headers=True, start='A1',)
```